# list of string formatting issue in request

Tags: java, groovy, graphql, jmeter, jmeter-5.0

I'm trying to load test my Graphql API using Jmeter's GraphQL HTTP Request. I'm reading a CSV file in JSR223 preprocessor to create an ArrayList. I'm loading the ArrayList to the parameter. When I'm using the parameter value, I get the error because of a formatting issue.
Query without using the parameter

```
query MyQuery {
  batchGetData(input_data: ["aqwedasd","aqwedasq"]) {
    data {
      value1
      value2
      value3
    }
  }
}
```

The body of JMeter request without the parameter. **The below request works fine without any issues.**

```
POST https://example.com/graphql

POST data:
{"operationName":null,"query":"query MyQuery {\n  batchGetData(input_data: [\"aqwedasd\",\"aqwedasq\"]) {\n    data {\n      value1\n      value2\n      value3\n    }\n  }\n}"}

[no cookies]
```

Now using the JSR223 preprocessor, I read a CSV file and created an ArrayList using the below script and added it to the **listdata** parameter.

```
def rows = new File("values.csv").readLines()
Collections.shuffle(rows)
ArrayList<String> listdata = new ArrayList<String>()
listdata  = rows.subList(0, 5)
vars.putObject("listdata", listdata)
```

Now in my query I'm using the above **listdata** parameter.

GraphQL query:

```
query MyQuery {
  batchGetData(input_data: ${listdata}) {
    data {
      value1
      value2
      value3
    }
  }
}
```

Now when I ran the thread group, the JMeter transforms the query into the below request body. This fails because it doesn't have **** like the previous request.

```
POST https://example.com/graphql

POST data:
{"operationName":null,"query":"query MyQuery {\n  batchGetData(input_data: ["aqwedasd","aqwedasq"]) {\n    data {\n      value1\n      value2\n      value3\n    }\n  }\n}"}

[no cookies]
```

I'm getting the below error for the above request

```
{
  "errors" : [ {
    "message" : "Invalid JSON payload in GraphQLAuth POST request.",
    "errorType" : "MalformedHttpRequestException"
  } ]
}
```

Please let me know if I'm doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You need to [escape quotation marks](https://www.edureka.co/community/23839/escaping-strings-in-json) which you're getting from the CSV file

You're sending:

```
(input_data: ["aqwedasd","aqwedasq"])
```

and it needs to be

```
(input_data: [\"aqwedasd\",\"aqwedasq\"])
```

My expectation is that instead of `vars.putObject("listdata", listdata)` you need to do something like:

```
def json = new groovy.json.JsonBuilder(listdata).toString()
def escapedJson = org.apache.commons.text.StringEscapeUtils.escapeJson(json)
vars.put('listdata', escapedJson)
```

More information on Groovy scripting in JMeter: [Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy)

Comment: I used the above code. In the request body, now the value looks like [\"\\\"aqwedasd\\\"\", \"\\\"aqwedasq\\\"\"]
I tried to use the json, and with that  the value looks like 
["\"aqwedasd\"","\"aqwedasq\""]